# Weird hover event issue

Tags: jquery

I have a weird question regarding the hover event. When I hover to the element (.helpImg), it will run 4-6 times of my codes inside the hover function.
I am not sure how to debug this. Anyone has ideas?? Thanks a lot.

```
function test(){


console.log('testcall'); //this will only output 1 time

$('.helpImg').hover(function(){

         console.log('call'); //when hover the class, this will output multiple times (4~6 times randomly).          

         //the animation below will play multiple times too
          tooltip.css('display', 'block');
          tooltip.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);


          tooltip.animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=10'},500);

        },function (){            
          $instance = $(this).css({'cursor': 'auto'});
          $('#tooltip-' + $instance.attr('id') ).hide(50);
          $(".js-tutorialTooltips").hide(50);
        })

}
```

Comment: Is your tooltip coming up over your .helpImg causing the hover to end?  After the 4-6 repeats it stays solid?

Comment: How many times are you calling `test()` also try adding a `stop()` before animate. `tooltip.stop().animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=10'},500);`

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely registering the hover event multiple times, try this for a quick fix:

```
$('.helpImg').not('.registered').addClass('registered').hover(function() { 
  //... your code
```

This filters out the helpImg nodes which have the class `registered`, adds the class `registered` to the others and registers the `hover` function on the others.

The better solution, however, is to find out why your hover event gets registered multiple times. In your code, you seem to have a function `test`, which includes registering the hover event. If you call `test` multiple times, hover will get registered multiple times.

So the best way to deal with this is to `console.log('register hover')` before your hover event handler and make it only get called 1 time.